# How to make an array in new file from a list of items

Tags: node.js

I have a file with a list of words like this

```
add
 blah
   blahblah
undo
```

In other words, there's whitespace at the beginning of some of the lines.

Using node.js, I'm doing this to remove the whitespace (which works fine)

```
var fs = require('fs')
var array = fs.readFileSync(myfile.txt).toString().split("\n");
for(i  in array){
   var k = array[i].trim();
   console.log(k);
}
```

but I would like to put the result in a new file like this

newfile.txt

```
var arr = ["add", "blah", "blahblah"];
```

Question: How to make an array in new file from a list of items

Comment: Wait, you want to store `var arr = ["add", "blah", "blahblah"];` in your file?

Comment: @ShanShan yes, because I then wish to use that array in a program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var fs = require('fs')
var inLines = fs.readFileSync('in.txt').toString().split("\n");
var trimmed = inLines.map(function (line) {
  return line.trim();
});
// remove any blank lines
var noEmpties = trimmed.filter(function (line) {
  return line;
});
var newData = 'var arr = ' + JSON.stringify(noEmpties) + ';\n'
fs.writeFileSync('newfile.txt', newData, 'utf8');
```